# login to outlook account by microsoft graph api without stay logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have a multi-user app.
The problem When a particular user logs in to Outlook, there is an option of staying logged in.
And when the same computer logs in to another user, it automatically logs in to the previous user's Outlook account.
The question is how to open the login outlook dialog without the option of remaining login

Comment: - Do you use any API to login to Outlook or just opening it by Outlook profile?

Comment: by outlook profile.

Comment: If it's just Outlook profile, then you may want to turn Outlook's profile prompt is on - it's described at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-outlook-profile-prompt-on-or-off-b6f08321-51ec-4c1d-8c25-3e26ea475d25 (refer Turn Outlook's profile prompt on or off section). Test this out and let me know how it goes.